# Amazon S3 CORS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

My web app is able to directly push data to my Amazon S3 bucket. Works great.... however, I am trying to use images.weserv.nl for cropping an image to a temporary cache they provide. The image I am providing them is already hosted inside my bucket.

My CORS rule for S3 have both:

```
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>http://images.weserv.nl</AllowedOrigin>
```

However, when I attempt to use the images.weserv.nl url with my direct link to the amazon bucket image, i get error related to a block in policy.
"?url= that you were looking for, because the hostname of the origin is unresolvable (DNS) or blocked by policy."

What do I need to update on my permissions/policy for S3 to enable the images.weserv.nl to be able to use the images I have on the S3 bucket?

For example:

```
http://images.weserv.nl/?url=http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/000aaabbbccc.jpg&crop=50,50,50,50
```

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks everyone

Comment: The page at http://images.weserv.nl says *"Requesting an image:

?url= (URL encoded) link to your image, without http://"*

Comment: Yes this was the problem! Thanks I missed that! Now everything is OK!

Answer (score 0):

Requesting Url cannot have the http:// included.